# Why does my modal jquery won't work when link to these .js files

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a pop-up modal that I need when to confirm if a user will do a certain action:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        $("#the-dialog").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height: 140,
        modal: true,
        buttons:{
            "Option One": function(){
                //Perform Action
                $(this).dialog("close");
                },
            Cancel: function(){
                //Do nothing
                $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This modal needs these two links to work :

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

It works okay, when I run it at my test page. Now I tried to integrate it to my main page and suddenly it doesn't work, **but** when I remove this two links it suddenly works fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: What errors do you get? And the versions of jQuery are different.

Comment: from what I can see you are loading 3 different jquery scripts. Just pick the newest one to avoid any conflicts.

Comment: @j08691 I receive '$(...).dialog is not a function'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to extend my explanation a bit, you are loading 3 different jquery scripts, at least 2 of which are different versions as well:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script> // v: 1.12.4

<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script> //this is ok, it's jQuery UI which extends jQuery

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script> // v: 1.4.2
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script> //don't know which versions is this one
```

The reason your modal doesn't work (and i'm pretty sure it's not the only thing not working if you keep digging into it) is that you're probably having some conflicts between them.

It makes no sense uploading 3 versions of the same script, except if you want a pile of bugs in your application. Just pick, preferably the newest one since that will most probably work with all your cases.

And one more thing to make sure is that your jquery script that you choose is the first one to load (so just make sure is the first script in your header).

Comment: Thanks, I'm still new to programming to I don't know this kinds of stuff

Answer (score 0):

you need to load only one jquery libs at the top of your script, all other go below that one

Answer (score 0):

Those last two lines in your post should be removed. They are loading older versions of JQuery. You only need to load JQuery once and JQuery UI once so the first two script tags in your post are all you need.

Answer (score 0):

You should use only these two Scripts:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Instead of these two:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

On the first two, you are referring your page to 2 scripts located on outside website (code.jquery.com).

On the second two: the first one refer to an outside website (ajax.googleapis.com) and the second one to your Scripts folder, for that you have to download the script, to place it in your Scriptsfolder and then to add a reference to it.

You have first of all to make a decision if you want your Scripts to depend on others servers or you want to download them and to refer your project to your downloaded Scripts.

If you included all the 4 links on your page that for sure won't work because you referrd to the same Script twice, you need one Script for jquery and one for jquery-ui.

Note that the jquery script always has to be the first because jquery-ui is based regular jquery.